# association list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, associations

I want to write a rule in prolog which gets the parameters

- **FAssoc**: Association list which contains the number of ways to climb a stair
- **U**: number of last step of the stairs
- **Key**: the current step that I am on, and
- **Steps**: a list with the possible numbers of stairs I can climb with each step.

I want to calculate from the step that I am until the last step the number of ways I can climb the stairs.

Examples :

```
list_to_assoc([1-1,2-0,3-0,4-1,5-0],Fassoc),
  calc_next(5, 1 , Fassoc ,  [1,2,6],F),
  assoc_to_list(F,L).
L = [1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-0].
```

However the answer I expect is `L = [1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-2].`
Because I can go `1->2->3->4->5.` or `1->5`.

I am using the function

```
calc_next(U,Key,FAssoc,[H|T],New):-
  (Limit is H+Key,
  Limit=<U->
  get_assoc(Limit,FAssoc,UntilNow),
  get_assoc(Key,FAssoc,ElH),
  Update0 is UntilNow+ElH,
  Update is Update0 mod 1000000009,
  put_assoc(Limit,FAssoc,Update,Assoc),
  get_assoc(Limit,FAssoc,Z),write('a'),
  calc_next(U,Key,Assoc,T,New)),!.

calc_next(U,Key,FAssoc,[H|T],New):-
  calc_next(U,Key,FAssoc,T,New),write('c'),!.
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you mean exactly by "number of ways to climb a stair". Can you explain / elaborate on your example a bit?

Comment: What does each tuple (`x-y`) mean? How this all works isn't clear to me. I'm a little fuzzy on how the answer `[1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-2]` is a result from being able to go `1->2->3->4->5` or `1->5`. And it leaves me wondering: why not `1->3->5`?